# Variable inside grep in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I have to search for a pattern inside a variable in Perl.
The pattern also needs to be inside a variable.
Here is what I have:

```
opendir(DIR,"reports/");
$poolname = $poolname."_";
@FILES= grep {/^$poolname\.[0-9]*.csv/} readdir(DIR);
@sorted= reverse sort @FILES;
```

The pattern I want to match is poolname_[0-9]*
(I'm trying to get the latest report for a pool here. [0-9]* is the unix timestamp of the file)

But the above regex is not working as expected. 
$sorted[0] doesn't have the required filename.
May I know what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: It's Perl, not PERL. It's not an acronym.

Comment: ok :) I thought it was Practical Extraction and Reporting Language

Comment: Do you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of the script? At a glance i see nothing wrong, although i would put `poolname_` directly into the regex.

Comment: Please show a list of your filenames. You'll append a underscore to `$poolname` and then search for a dot afterwards inside the regexp.

Comment: Also, what does `$poolname` contain at the start of the script?

Comment: @dgw: Good catch with the dot.

Comment: $poolname=$cgi->param("x"); And thanks for pointing out that dot I removed it (i had meant that for concatenating prev part of regex to later). But yet no avail

Comment: x_1332827070.csv x_1333366051.csv etc. represents pattern of the filenames

Comment: I never understand people who will take time out of their day to type something like, "It's Perl, not PERL. It's not an acronym."  So many people here that take themselves entirely too seriously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that somewhere before the snippet in the question, there is an assignment equivalent to:

```
my $poolname = "poolname";
```

then you say you are searching for:

```
poolname_[0-9]*          # Presumably, poolname_[0-9]*.csv in fact
```

but your regex is searching for:

```
poolname_\.[0-9]*.csv    # Probably should have a backslash before the .csv
```

The patterns you seek will not be matched by your regex; remove the `\.` to get the result you require.

```
opendir(DIR,"reports/") or die "$!";
@FILES  = grep { /^${poolname}_[0-9]*\.csv/ } readdir(DIR);
@sorted = reverse sort @FILES;
closedir(DIR);
```

---

Given a directory `reports` containing files:

```
x_1332827070.csv
x_1333366051.csv
x_1333A66051.csv
y_1332827070.csv
```

this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $poolname = "x";
opendir(DIR,"reports/") or die "$!";
my @FILES  = grep { /^${poolname}_[0-9]*\.csv/ } readdir(DIR);
my @sorted = reverse sort @FILES;
closedir(DIR);

print "$_\n" for @sorted;
```

produces the output:

```
x_1333366051.csv
x_1332827070.csv
```

If that is not what you're after, your comments and your question are misleading.

Comment: x_1332827070.csv
x_1333366051.csv etc. represents pattern of the filenames